# I'm trying to print form inputs data on the console of node.js, but the console is showing empty Curly braces

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to get form inputs data on the console of **node.js**, but, it's showing an **empty Curly brace**.

I used **postman** to check whether the data is received or not, it's working well, data has been **received successfully** on the terminal console.

**<-------- I have taken the below steps to get the data from POSTMAN -------->**

*step-1*: created a **new collection** and selected a **post request**

*step-2*: entered request URL
**(http://localhost/loginandsingup)**

*step-3*: in the header section, selected **Content-Type** in the key column and the value is **application/json**

*step-4*: added some **data** in the body section

```
{
   "username": "shyam",
   "email": "kumbamshyam955@gmai.com",
   "mobilenumber": 6547896587,
   "password": "superman145",
   "confirmpassword": "superman145",
   "checkbox": true
}
```

*step-5*: finally I clicked on the send button

**Output from the postman, on terminal**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61047/e3190b4a-b5a4-4806-9d45-c1f09c74212a
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
application had started successfully on port 80
database conencted successfuly
{
  username: 'shyam',
  email: 'kumbamshyam955@gmai.com',
  mobilenumber: 6547896587,
  password: 'superman145',
  confirmpassword: 'superman145',
  checkbox: true
}
```

**<-------- Code to get the form inputs data from locally hosted website -------->**

**// I used node.js for the backend //**

**app.js** (Backend code)

```
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require('path');

dotenv.config({path: './config.env'})
const User = require('./model/userschema.js')
require('./db/database-connection.js')

const port = process.env.PORT

app.use(express.json()); 

app.use(require('./router/auth'))

const staticpath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
app.use(express.static(staticpath));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/view'));

const middleware = (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log("hello i'm middleware")
    next();
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render('home.pug');
})

app.get('/loginandsingup', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render('loginandsingup.pug');
})

app.get('/customerservice', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render('customerservice.pug');
})

app.get('/product', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render('product.pug');
})

app.get('/404', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).render('404.pug')
})


app.use((req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/404')
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`application had started successfully on port ${port}`)
})
```

**router/auth.js** (Backend code)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

require('../db/database-connection');
const User = require('../model/userschema');


router.post('/loginandsingup',(req, res) => {
    const body = req.body
    console.log(body);
    res.json({message: req.body});
})

module.exports = router;
```

**loginandsingup.pug** (pug code)

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    //- meta(http-equiv='refresh' content='30') 
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    title Mens Fashion | Login & singup
    style
      include ../public/css/login-and-singup-folder/loginstyle.css
      include ../public/css/main-css/style.css
    link(href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet",integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3", crossorigin="anonymous")
    link(rel="preconnect", href="https://fonts.googleapis.com")
    link(rel="preconnect", href="https://fonts.gstatic.com", crossorigin="")
    link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap",rel="stylesheet")
  body(style="background: rgba(236, 236, 236, 1)")
    .loding-img-container
      img#loading(src="images/Rolling scg.svg", alt="")
    include navbar.pug
    #login-and-singup-section.container
      #login-and-singup-main-container.container.bg-light
        #login-and-singup-container-1.login-and-singup-container.my-5
              form#login-form
                .mb-3
                    label.form-label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Email address
                    input#login-email.form-control(type='email' aria-describedby='emailHelp' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Email")
                .mb-3
                    label.form-label(for='exampleInputPassword1') Password
                    input#login-password.form-control(type='password' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter password")
                button.btn.btn-success#login-submit-btn(type='submit') Sing in
                button.btn.btn-outline-primary#logins-singup-btn(type='button') sing up

        #login-and-singup-container-2.login-and-singup-container.my-5
              .error-images.mb-3
                img(src="images/error icon.png", alt="")
                h1 Error !
                span#error-msg Please Enter Corrext Email
              form#singup-form(method='post' action='/loginandsingup') 
                .mb-3
                    label.form-label(for='username') User name
                    input#username.form-control(name='username' type='text' )
                .mb-3
                    label.form-label(for='email') Email
                    input#email.form-control(name='email' type='Email')
                .mb-3
                    label.form-label(for='mobilenumber') Enter number
                    input#mobilenumber.form-control(name='mobilenumber' type='number')
                .mb-3
                    label.form-label(for='password') Enter New Password
                    input#password.form-control(name='password' type='password')
                .mb-3
                    label.form-label(for='confirmpassword') Confirm Password
                    input#confirmpassword.form-control(name='confirmpassword' type='password')
                .form-check.login-checkbox-container
                    input.bg-danger.border-danger#tandcCheckbox.form-check-input(name='tandcCheckbox' type='checkbox' checked)
                    label.form-check-label.m-0(for='tandcCheckbox') Agree To Our 
                      a.text-danger Terms And Conditions
                .form-check.login-checkbox-container
                    input.border-danger.form-check-input#upcoming-notification(name='offersmail' type='checkbox')
                    label.form-check-label.m-0(for='exampleCheck1') recieve upcomimg offers and events mails
                button.btn.btn-success#new-user-submit-btn(type='submit') Submit
                button.btn.btn-outline-primary#signups-login-btn(type='button') Login

script(type='text/javascript' src='js/loginandsingup.js')
  


script(
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  ntegrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB",
  crossorigin="anonymous"
)
script(
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13",
  crossorigin="anonymous"
)
```

**Output from the locally hosted website, on terminal**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55622/66b83ad8-4e15-4359-9d7b-1d638262c70a
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
application had started successfully on port 80
database conencted successfuly
{}
```

**Any solution to this problem

Comment: are you parsing the request? https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**------->It's working**✌️, after including the `body-parser` module

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

router.post('/loginandsingup', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(body);
    res.json({ message: req.body.username });

})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default forms submit as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` enctype. NodeJs cant understand it by default so you need to install and configure `body-parser` module.

Comment: it's working, @AdiL IsmaiL

Comment: @Shyam cool, tag me in your future questions if any, ill try to help